# spring mvc login/logout using session

Tags: spring-mvc

In this login example i am trying to add session to the user.The basic login feature works fine.When i go back to the home page i cannot access the page that is in the log success page.I need to login again.I am new to spring, please tell me how i should get a session.

**Logincontoller.java**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    private LoginService loginService;

    @RequestMapping("login.html")
    public String toLogin(Model model) {
        Login login = new Login(); 
        model.addAttribute("login",login);
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="login.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView  doLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute ("login") Login login, 
            BindingResult bindingresult,HttpSession session ) {
         ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("login");
        if(!bindingresult.hasErrors()){
            if(!loginService.authenticateUser(login)){
                bindingresult.addError(new ObjectError("invalid", "Invalid Credentials!!!"));
                return new ModelAndView("error");
            }
            else{
                session.setAttribute("login", login);
                view.setViewName("success");
            }
        }

         return view;
}

    @RequestMapping("/logout")
      public String logout(HttpSession session ) {
         session.invalidate();
         return "redirect:/login.html";
      }

}
```

Comment: Are you seeing a JSESSIONID being set in your cookies?

Comment: How to see that? First of all code correct?

Comment: Other than the fact I would say to use something like Spring Security rather than rolling your own solution I don't see anything wrong with the code.  You can use a myriad of browser debug tools to see cookies.  Google's Chrome has Dev Tools built in, IE has some dev tools (may have to install them), FireFox has FireBug.  I don't use Opera or Safari, but I'd bet they have some tools as well.  Worse case, crack open the folder where the cookies are stored for your browser and open them in a text editor.

Comment: I am new to spring.I dont want to use spring security. That is why trying this way. I will check firebug option.

Comment: The reason I mention Spring Security is that, at least in general practice, rolling your own security solutions are typically a bad investment. Companies like Google, Facebook, and the like can get away with it as they have brilliant people working there that specialize in security that are probably WAY smarter than any of us. And even then those companies still get *hacked*. Not that using Spring Security will fix that 100%, but a lot of smart people have put a lot of time and thought into it.  I am not trying to persuade you, just speaking from my personal beliefs and opinions.

Comment: @ CodeChimp  i can see the jsessionid.It holds a value.

Comment: Is it the same value before and after you set the session variable?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed something.  Why are you setting login in the session in the `doLogin`, but you are setting a new login in the `toLogin`? Also, are you aware that the `@SessionAttribute` could be used at the class-level of your Controller to indicate to Spring to save the 'login' to the session when you save it to the Model?

Comment: Yes the values are same. Please can you change the code.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are setting the `'login'` in the `Model` in `toLogin`.  Since you are storing it in session in the other method, why would you not be checking session and storing it there in this one?  Again, `@SessionAttribute` can help make that easier so that you only have to work with the `Model`.

Comment: I don't understand your second line.

Comment: To clarify: Your `toLogin()` method stores a `Login` called `login` into the model.  Your `doLogin()` takes a `Login` as a form post (`@ModelAttribute` in the parameters) and eventually puts it into the Session. So, you are creating a blank login in the first method, basically tossing it away, and then creating another based on the form post and putting into session. Not sure why you are doing that. And if you want to put something in session, you can add an `@SessionAttributes` at the class-level of your Controller, then you only have to deal with the Model and Spring does the rest.

Comment: Login page is my home page. That is why i am using toLogin(). I'll try to use @SessionAttributes. Is there a way i can find whether a session is maintained or not.

Comment: Sessions are created when a client first opens a page.  The server will set the JSESSIONID cookie, or put it in the URL if it can't set the cookie.  The JSESSIONID is what links the client's requests to the session that lives on the server.

Answer (score 2):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout")
    public String logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("logout()");
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
        httpSession.invalidate();
        return "redirect:loginformRichUI.html";
    }
```

Comment: This does not work when I press the back button, It shows I am logged in.